# Split columns in R

Tags: r, excel

I have  a huge set of data with 35k + Rows of data. i import this data from a `.csv` file in R and do the same in Excel. In excel it shows me 8 different headings of columns with 35k Rows. But in R, it shows me only one column name with all the column names in one big column. I have tried with the following R code:

```
> YR1999 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/---/---/YR1999.csv", header=TRUE, quote="\"")

> class(YR1999)
[1] "data.frame"

> names(YR1999)
[1] "SYMBOL.......SHORT_NAME...........INFO_4THE.OPENING_RATE.HIGH_RATE..LOW_RATE.CURR_RATE.CURR_TURNOVER"

> dim(YR1999)
[1] 35647     1
> colnames(YR1999) <- c("Symbol", "Stock Name", "Date", "Open-Rate","High-Rate", "Low-Rate", "Current-Rate", "Turnover")
Fehler in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Symbol", "Stock Name", "Date",  : 
  Attribut 'names' [8] muss dieselbe Länge haben wie der Vektor [1]
```

In Excel I see for each column name a different column but in R I dont. I would like to separate this one name to 8 columns as in the original data, can any one suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: You may need to use the correct delimiter i.e. `sep=`

Comment: are you sure you are saving the excel file as "Comma Separated Values (.csv)"?

Comment: If you have saved the files like @pcantalupo suggested, then you will probaly need `read.csv2` instead of `read.csv` because in most European countries the comma is used as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.

Comment: i also tried with read.csv2 with additional Parameters, but it still shows me only one column with many rows. @pcantalupo I have imported the .txt file in excel as well as in R, in Excel it worked, so i saved this file as .csv in order to open in R.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `read.csv("~/Desktop/---/---/YR1999.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE, quote="\"")` or `read.csv("~/Desktop/---/---/YR1999.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, quote="\"")`. You can actually look up in the excel which separation (";" or ",") is used.

Comment: I have tried it with both csv and csv2 adding the additional parameters as you mentioned, but the result is same. I have even tried opening the both file formats- .txt and .csv, also tried .csv2, but it always shows me one column with many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
install.packages("do")
library(do)
col_split(x = YR1999[,1],split = '-')
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).